# How to setup Identity 2 in MVC 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I am working on a new project using MVC 6. As the identity 3.0 is not yet production ready, I am trying to implement Identity 2.0. I have customized the User and Roles but I am stuck on using Identity service like in MVC 6 using Identity 3 we subscribe by UseIdentity() and AddIdentity(). It seems that these two methods are present in Identity 3.0 only. I am actively looking for any solution to add Identity 2.0 in MVC 6. Please help.